# Push and Pop methods on singly linked list in python

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

-- For this assignment we are supposed to create push_back, pop_back, and pop_front methods using the code provided from the professor.

I keep getting an error 
"AssertionError: main.LinkedList object at 0x106ec7dd0>> != 1"

My guess is that the return in the pop and push methods are returning the reference to the value in the linked list instead of the actual values held in these nodes. I am completely stumped. I have asked around and everyone says the same thing. You're references are messed up, but I cannot figure out specifically what is wrong and how to go about fixing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Also if anyone would like to recommend forums for beginner's on questions such as this, that would be greatly appreciated as well. I did already post on stackoverflow, but I am open to any other suggestions.

Here is the source code.

'''--------------------------------------------------------------'''

''' ----------- This Block Provided By Instructor ----------- '''

class LinkedList(object):

```
class Node(object):
    # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    ''' no need for get or set, we only access the values inside the
        LinkedList class. and really, never have setters. '''


    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node

def __init__(self, initial=None):

    self.front = self.back = self.current = None
    self.next_node = self.current

def empty(self):
    return self.front == self.back == None

def __iter__(self):
    self.current = self.front
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.current:
        tmp = self.current.value
        self.current = self.current.next_node
        return tmp
    else:
        raise StopIteration()

def push_front(self, value):
    new = self.Node(value, self.front)
    if self.empty():
        self.front = self.back = new
    if self.empty() is not None:
        self.front = new
```

'' ^^^^^^^ This Block Provided By Instructor ^^^^^^^ '''

```
''' I need help with following three methods'''

def pop_front(self):
    if self.empty():
        return None
    tmp = self.front.value
    self.front = self.front.next_node
    if not self.front:
        self.back = None
    return tmp

def push_back(self, value):
    new = self.Node(value, self.back)
    if self.empty():
        self.back = self.front = new
    if self.empty() is not None:
        if self.back.next_node is None:
            self.current = self.back
            self.back.next_node = new


def pop_back(self):
    if self.empty():
        return None
    tmp = self.back.value
    if not self.front.next_node:
        self.front = self.back = None
    else:
        while self.front.next_node is not self.back:
            self.front = self.next_node
        self.front.next_node = None
        self.back = self.front
    return tmp
```

''' Begin Tests '''

class TestPrintMethods(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test(self):
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.push_front(1)
    linked_list.push_front(2)
    linked_list.push_front(3)
    linked_list.pop_front()
    print(linked_list.front.value)
    print(linked_list.back.value)
    print(linked_list)
```

class TestEmpty(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test(self):
    self.assertTrue(LinkedList().empty())
```

class TestPushFrontPopBack(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test(self):
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.push_front(1)
    linked_list.push_front(2)
    linked_list.push_front(3)
    self.assertFalse(linked_list.empty())
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), 1)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), 2)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), 3)
    self.assertTrue(linked_list.empty())
```

class TestPushFrontPopFront(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test(self):
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.push_front(1)
    linked_list.push_front(2)
    linked_list.push_front(3)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 3)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 2)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 1)
    self.assertTrue(linked_list.empty())
```

class TestPushBackPopFront(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test(self):
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.push_back(1)
    linked_list.push_back(2)
    linked_list.push_back(3)
    self.assertFalse(linked_list.empty())
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 1)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 2)
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 3)
    self.assertTrue(linked_list.empty())
```

class TestPushBackPopBack(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test(self):
    linked_list = LinkedList()
    linked_list.push_back(1)
    linked_list.push_back("foo")
    linked_list.push_back([3, 2, 1])
    print(linked_list)
    self.assertFalse(linked_list.empty())
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), [3, 2, 1])
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), "foo")
    self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_back(), 1)
    self.assertTrue(linked_list.empty())
```

'''--------------------------------------------------------------'''

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to call these methods

```
self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front, 1)
```

should be

```
self.assertEqual(linked_list.pop_front(), 1)
```

Comment: Oh! Silly me. Now I am getting

"AssertionError: 1 != [3, 2, 1]" 

And am not sure whats wrong with the rest of my code. 

Im also still getting 

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_node'"

Which to me suggests that there is an issue when referencing the list still.